# When does Firestore automatically retry plain document writes?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

1. If I perform an update operation on a document in Firestore, and I know for certain that the document exists, what possible reason, outside of my control, could an error be generated?
2. And if an error is generated, is the update automatically retried?
3. Or is this update only automatically retried if there is no connection and Firestore's offline capabilities take over?

Comment: Transactions and write operations that happen while offline are the only writes that Firestore SDKs automatically retry. What other type of error were you considering?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen this link says transactions fail when offline? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Comment: Correct, it might have been clearer if I'd added an extra comma there: Transactions, and write operations that happen while offline, are the only writes that Firestore SDKs automatically retry. But my question remains the same: What types of error were you considering?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen well I guess that's what I'm asking you. If I update a document that I know for certain exists, as an example, what possible errors could be returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. If I perform an update-data operation on a document in Firestore, and I know for certain that the document exists, what possible reason, outside of my control, could an error be generated?

A common error that can arise, is when the Firebase servers reject an operation due to improper security rules. Meaning that you are not allowed to do that particular operation.

> 2. And if an error is generated, is the update automatically retried?

No, that will not happen while online.

> 3. Or is this update only automatically retried if there is no connection and Firestore's offline capabilities take over?

Yes, that will indeed happen. All operations that take place while offline, are added to a queue. Behind the scenes, Firestore SDK tries to reconnect until the devices regain connectivity. Once the user regains the connection, every change that is made while offline will be updated on Firebase servers. In other words, all update operations will be committed on the server, as long as you have proper rules.

Comment: So the only operations that are actually "retried" by Firestore are (1) transactions that did not go through but not because of something the programmer did wrong (i.e. the underlying documents changed) and (2) any write operation (set data, update data, batch write) that was done while offline?

Comment: Yes, that's entirely correct.